# What are these little balls in my sardines?

Tags: eggs, food-identification, sardines

I opened a container of sardines and found loads of little round balls in what appears to be its belly.

[image: picture of the sardine]

What are these things? Are they eggs the sardine was going to lay (or whatever it's called for a fish) or something it ate? Are they good to eat, or should I throw them out?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, that is sardine roe. In Portugal it is considered a delicacy on a par with caviar.

Answer (score 2):

I found roe in mine for the first time today and was a little off put until I realized within seconds what it was.  I did a search to confirm, YEP!  It's roe.  Just finished eating every last bite of it.  I'm not easily grossed out.

Comment: Try it on toast with some butter...